# Experiment with incompatibility of Java serilization

Tags: java, serialization, version, compatibility

I understand Java serialization conceptually, however I am pretty much bewildered with the version compatibility of a serializable object. When "version" is referred, does it mean:

either two classes of a hierarchical relationship, and one of which has a addition/deduction of attributes?

or two classes complied with different compilation versions?

or both?

My understanding is that we have to keep the suid consistent, which is checked by JVM for the version compatibility.

As a result I devised an experiment trying to test the version incompatibility of java serialization, the code snippet is as below, in which I made the suid different:

```
    public static class Incompatible implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int i;
    public Incompatible(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }
    public int getI(){
        return i;
    }
}

public static class IncompFoo extends Incompatible {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    public IncompFoo(int i){
        super(i);
    }
}

@Test
public void incompatibleTest() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("foo.ser"));
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(new IncompFoo(10));
    oos.close();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("foo.ser"));
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Incompatible foo = (Incompatible)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    Assert.assertEquals(10, foo.getI());

}
```

I was expected an InvalidClassException as these two classes have different suid. To my surprise the test went through all right.

Which part was wrong? Do we have a simple way to create a InvalidClassException?

Comment: You have to read with a different version of the same class than you wrote. You haven't changed the code for a class so you shouldn't expect a problem.

Comment: You need to study the Object Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example writes an object, reads it and casts it to its superclass. Nothing interesting happens there, even though you hoped the cast would somehow break things (it doesn't, it's just a cast and a valid one).

Write an instance of the class to the file, change it's `serialVersionUID`, recompile the class and try to read the serialized object back. Forget any super/subclass shenanigans.